# How can I move mouse in browser window?

Tags: javascript, flash, activex, mouse, move

I'd like to move mouse in my site browser window like here: www.lmsify.com.
How can I do this?
(javascript, flash, activex)

Regards,
LisaM

Comment: Why would you do this?  This would cause me serious annoyance were a site to start playing with my mouse pointer...

Comment: In flash you can call `Mouse.hide()` and then use `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` to move an element that looks like a mouse.

Comment: @Paddy, there are a few good reasons to want to move a mouse. FPS games, guided interfaces, and tutorials are a few that I can think of as legitimate reasons.

Comment: But are there any abbility to move mouse? Not image?

Comment: Ultimately moving the mouse is a privilege the internet can't be trusted with.

Comment: May be we can install some acriveX?

Comment: @Lisa: You could for in-house stuff, if you want to limit your in-house people to using IE. For general 'net stuff, ActiveX is a non-starter. Only IE supports it, and even in IE, users get scary warnings about untrusted content, which is by default disabled.

Comment: Lisa, what is the actual effect you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not really moving the mouse cursor (you can't do that with browser-based JavaScript; I can't speak for Flash and I stay away from ActiveX), they're moving an image that looks like a mouse cursor (in their case, http://www.lmsify.com/cursor.png).

You can move elements around the page using positioning (absolute, relative) and position properties (`left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`). For instance, here's how to make an absolutely-positioned version of that cursor jump left and down each time it's clicked:

```
document.getElementById('theImage').onclick = function() {
  var left, top;

  left = parseInt(this.style.left, 10) + 10;
  top  = parseInt(this.style.top, 10) + 10;
  this.style.left = left + "px";
  this.style.top = top + "px";
};
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/uxexo3)

But obviously that's very crude. Various libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) + [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) can help you animate elements.

Comment: Nice demo, but what about controlling mouse possition?

Comment: @Lisa: I said in my opening sentence, you can't in JavaScript, I wouldn't know about Flash, and I do (and recommend) stay away from ActiveX. Don't know about Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move the mouse cursor in a browser. It can be simulated by moving an image with JavaScript or flash.